# Como personalizar el formulario de registro y modificación de usuarios en el panel de administración de django?

Tags: django

He creado el siguiente modelo de usuario con el fin de agregar el campo email

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        _("email address"),
        unique=True
        )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username}'
```

En forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','username')
      
    
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('email','username',)
```

En admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = User
    
    list_display = ['email', 'username',]

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Todo esto funciona bien para poner como *USERNAME_FIELD* el email

El único problema es que en admin me sigue pidiendo el username como dato principal para agregar usuarios

[image: muestra de la parte que deseo cambiar por email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione .
He tenido que modificar algunos parámetros en admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = User
    
    list_display = ['email', 'username',]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email','username', 'password1', 'password2')}),
            )

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]